# appear div transparent initially and appear prominent or clear by jquery

Tags: jquery

suppose i have link and i want that when people click on that link then a DIV appear on the page at center initially transparent and gradually becomes prominent or clear by jquery.

here is one example page. just go to the link http://www.purolator.com/purolator/ship-track/tracking-summary.page and put the **602336548147** into the textbox and click on track button. then a tabular data appear with another link called **Verify entry / refine search**

just click on that link and see a how a div appear with a effect and stay at center of the page when resize. i want to mimic that effect. so just guide me how can i do this with jquery. thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called a Modal Window. You can make the similar effect using [Simple jQuery Modal Window Tutorial](http://www.queness.com/post/77/simple-jquery-modal-window-tutorial).

You need to have a `div` already with or without content, but should exist. And you just need to position it and show it here:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {  

    //select all the a tag with name equal to modal
    $('a[name=modal]').click(function(e) {
        //Cancel the link behavior
        e.preventDefault();
        //Get the A tag
        var id = $(this).attr('href');

        //Get the screen height and width
        var maskHeight = $(document).height();
        var maskWidth = $(window).width();

        //Set height and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
        $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

        //transition effect     
        $('#mask').fadeIn(1000);    
        $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.8);  

        //Get the window height and width
        var winH = $(window).height();
        var winW = $(window).width();

        //Set the popup window to center
        $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
        $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);

        //transition effect
        $(id).fadeIn(2000); 

    });

    //if close button is clicked
    $('.window .close').click(function (e) {
        //Cancel the link behavior
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#mask, .window').hide();
    });     

    //if mask is clicked
    $('#mask').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });         

});

</script>
```

Comment: i hope u did not see the effect of the link i given. i was looking for that effect rather not to show a div. i my concern was to have that effect.ur code is not right for what i am looking for. thanks for ur time.